# Using linq to find out the nearest data with the given latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sqlgeography

I have a data table which stores has data stored as per latitude and longitude.
  [image]

I need to use LINQ query to filter in this datable and find the nearest location from the given latitude and longitude.

For example:
28.9873 -- Latitude,
80.1652 -- Longitude

Comment: You should either (best approach imo) use a geographical data type within your DB and let the DB sort that out for you, otherwise I would create a stored procedure that delivers the nearest location based on the minimum of the sum of differences in Lat and Lng.

Comment: @mjwills its stored in SQL Server.

Comment: I'd recommend https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11904/find-closest-lat-long-to-an-input-lat-long-sql-server-2008 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var minDistance = collection.Min( x => Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow( wantedLatitude - x.Latitude ) + Math.Pow( wantedLongitude - x.Longitude )));

var closestLocation = collection.First( x => Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow( wantedLatitude - x.Latitude ) + Math.Pow(wantedLongitude - x.Longitude )) == minDistance );
```

It goes through collection twice, so I suggest to optimize it by finding Min element in first run, you can easily find how to do it in other questions on SO, and to and encapsulate calculation of distance to own method, but you get the idea.